# A problem on finding area of the surface of a hotel

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I am learning vector calculus using *Vector Calculus* by Marsden and Tromba. In the chapter *Integrals over Paths and Surfaces*, I went across the following problem:

> A restaurant is being built on the side of a mountain. The mountain's surface is given by the equation $z+x^2+y^2=4R^2$ and the hotel is the cylinder $ (y-R)^2+x^2=R^2 $. What will be the curved surface area of the hotel?

The book provides the following figure:
[image: The hotel and the mountain]

Originally the question has asked a lot more, but right now, I only have problems in this part.

Initially I had no idea how to approach the problem, but slowly I came up with this solution.

On the $yz$ plane, the surface of the hotel projects the region $R$ bounded by $z=4R^2$, $y=2R$, and $z=4R^2-y^2$. The surface of the hotel will be symmetric around the $yz$ plane. So, if we calculate the surface area of one of the sides, the whole surface area can be calculated easily. Along the positive $x$ axis, the surface of the hotel will be given as $x=\sqrt{R^2-(y-R)^2}$.

So, surface area of that side can be given as:
$$ \begin{align} A(S) &= \iint_R \sqrt{ \Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\Big)^2+1}\,\mathrm dA \\ &= \int\limits_0^{2R}\int\limits^{4R^2}_{4R^2-y^2}\sqrt{\frac{(y-R)^2}{R^2-(y-R)^2}+1}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\\ &= R \int\limits_0^{2R}\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{R^2-(y-R)^2}}\,\mathrm dy \\ & \overset{y-R=R \sin u}{=} R^3 \int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+\sin u)^2 \,\mathrm du \\ A(S)&= \frac{3\pi R^3}2 \end{align}$$

Is this correct? If no, what is the mistake? If yes, are there any other ways to approach the problem? I don't think that it is correct, primarily due to the reason that it is not dimensionally correct. Except that, I have no good reason to say that the answer is incorrect. Maybe this is due to $z$ not having dimension of length, but that of area.

I tried to find the solution manual for the book, but didn't find any. Any help regarding that too would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem in your set up is the lower bound of the $z$ of the projection in yz-plane. You are writing it as $z = 4R^2 - y^2$ but that is not true. See a simpler set up in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler to see that the surface area element of a cylinder of radius $R$ is $dS = R \cdot d\theta \cdot dz$

The hotel surface is given by $(y-R)^2+x^2=R^2$. So it is easier to use the parametrization for cylindrical surface $x = R \cos\theta, y = R + R\sin\theta, z = z$

At the intersection of paraboloid surface and the cylinder,

$z = 4R^2 - x^2 - y^2 = 4R^2 - R^2 \cos^2\theta - R^2 (1 + \sin^2\theta + 2 \sin\theta) = 2R^2(1 - \sin\theta)$

So the curved surface area of the hotel is given by,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{2R^2(1 - \sin\theta)}^{4R^2} R ~ dz ~ d\theta = 4 \pi R^3$

Comment: Thanks a lot. A coincidence is that I had got the same answer as yours, when I had initially tried to calculate the surface area using line integrals, which I didn't mention in the post thinking that the idea is vague. Seems like I was correct.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari yes if you calculated using line integral with $f(z)$ as integrand and you got the same answer, yes that should be correct